# Regular expression to get all text after the second spase from the end

Tags: regex

I use service kimono to parse some data and this service has specific 3-group regular expression tool.

first group is text before the needed one, than expression for text I need, and third is expression after the needed text.

So, by default it looks like:

```
/^()([^]*?)()$/
```

I have a sentence like `{Olive oil in glass bottle 500 ml.}` and I need to get only text after second space from the end, except last point, so that result should be:

```
500 ml
```

Any of my tries have not succeeded.

Comment: Which language are you running? did you want to print the text from single line or from multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

If you have support of lookahead you can try this.

```
^(.*?(?=\s[^ ]*\s[^ ]*$))([^.]*?)(.)$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/35

or

```
^([^\d]*)([^.]*?)(.)$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/36

or

```
^(.*?\s)([^\s]*\s[^\s]*)(\.)$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/37

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex and then get the string you want from group index 1.

```
^.*?\s(?=\S*\s\S*$)([^.]*)\.
```

`(?=\S*\s\S*$)` positive lookahead asserts that there must be a single space exists.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xM2sY2/2)

Comment: I don't know why, but on kimonolabs.com it wont work. :(

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(\S+\s+\S+)\.$
```

The text you want is in the group 1.